# I want to animate 0 counting up to 100

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a 10 slide presentation and I'm pretty happy with it but it looks a little stale, I want to add some animations and nice effects in there.

I currently have some text that reads '100%' i would like the page upon load to be at zero and then quickly count up to 100.

How would I do this?

Comment: Please show us what code you have ... CSS, HTML, and/or jQuery to see where you are and what would be appropriate to move forward.  Also, any code you have attempted would be good, as well.

Comment: I don't have anything so far. literally just have a span with a class of counter. Been googling but can't find what I need. My jquery and java is very basic

Comment: You have some HTML with the 100% ...

Comment: looking at the answer below, do I need to set up a variable for my span and set it equal to zero? and swap that for the count variable?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 0;
    var counting = setInterval(function(){
        if(count < 101) {
            $('.text').text(count + '%');
            count++
        } else {
            clearInterval(counting)
        }
    }, 10);
});
```